# openCti sforce is undefined in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, opencti

I have downloaded openCti js library from the below link

> mysalesforcedomain/support/api/53.0/lightning/opencti_min.js

Added it as a static resource then loaded the openCti library in the aura component

HTML:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.openCti}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.handleOpenCtiLoaded}" />
```

JavaScript:

```
handleOpenCtiLoaded: function (component, event, helper) {
    console.log('sforce open ct', sforce)
}
```

Please confirm if openCti is supported in aura components, if yes then please suggest how to use the same.